# iOS 7.1 Why is my UIScrollView scrolling away on showing keyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have a UIScrollView designed with IB.

```
UIView
  UIScrollView
    UIView
      UITextField
      UIButton
      ...
```

If I tap on the text field the view scrolls away towards the upper left corner of the screen before the keyboard is appearing. The space above the keyboards remains empty. I can scroll back the view if I drag in this empty space.

I have googled around, but found only postings where users want to scroll UIScrollView. I want the view to stay where it is.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you added any code in the text view delegates ?

Comment: In between I hide the keyboard on return.

Comment: What happens if you disable the scrolling on the scrollView when the user taps the text view ?

Comment: The scroll view automatically shows the text field if the keyboard would cover it. If that isn't working correctly, it sounds like you may have a faulty `contentSize`. How is the content size for this scroll view being determined and set?

Comment: @CW0007007: The view scrolls away, but cannot be scrolled back.

Comment: @matt: The content size is set to the size of the inner view in IB by hand.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have code that are not showing us???? It sounds like you are (wrongly) doing something in response to the keyboard appearing.

Comment: Please download and run my example bk2ch10p522textFieldScrollView (from https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples). You will see that when you tap in the _top_ text field and the keyboard appears, nothing happens. But if you tap in the _bottom_ text field, the scroll view correctly scrolls to reveal it. My code responds to the keyboard showing by adjusting the scroll view's insets but the scrolling is automatic.

Comment: @matt: I am sorry, I do not respond to any keyboard events but return key.

Comment: The question you have to answer is how does your project differs from mine. Mine shows how it _should_ work.

Comment: @matt: I found the problem, the content insets where not 0.

Comment: Good work! That would do it...

Comment: @matt: content insets 0 means no more scrolling.

Comment: Because you have incorrectly designed the constraints.

Comment: "The content size is set to the size of the inner view in IB by hand" but that is not working because your xib or storyboard has auto layout turned on. In that case you must _design_ the content size into the _constraints_ around the content UIView.

Comment: I have codified our discussion into an actual answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happened.

1. You designed the whole thing in Interface Builder.
2. The scroll view was not scrolling, so you set its `contentSize` in code to the size of the scroll view's primary subview (what I like to call the *content view*).
3. The scroll view was *still* not scrolling, so you munged the content insets - and this caused the problem that brought you here.

Your mistake was (3). Instead, you should have thought more about (2), i.e., why isn't my scroll view scrolling even though I have given it a nice big content size?

The answer is that, in a storyboard or xib that has auto layout turned on, that's not what you do. What you do is use *constraints* from the content view to its superview (the scroll view), on all four sides. Set the `constant` for all four constraints to zero. This causes the content size to match the size of the content view, *automatically*.

Comment: No problem! I'm sorry it took so long to shake it out.

Comment: What do you mean by setting "all four constraints to zero" ?